# Show map markers on hover

Tags: javascript, leaflet, openstreetmap

I have a list of links to several locations. I would like to add map marker to my OSM map and remove it when I hover out, while adding new one I hover over etc. I've been been able to add marker to the map on hover but I'm not able to remove them.

**HTML**

```
<a href="/..." onmouseover="mkron(this)" onmouseout="mkroff()">...</a>
```

**JS**

```
function mkron(x) {
   // some code to get lat lon 
   L.marker([lat, lon]).addTo(map);
}

function mkroff() {
    markers.clearLayers();
}
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Could you provide clearLayers code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that you add the marker directly to the map instead of adding it to the LayerGroup / FeatureGroup `markers`.

I don't know the rest of your code but it should look like that:

```
var markers = L.featureGroup().addTo(map);

function mkron(x) {
   // some code to get lat lon 
   L.marker([lat, lon]).addTo(markers);
}

function mkroff() {
    markers.clearLayers();
}
```

The other variant would be to store the layer in a global variable and then remove it from the map:

```
var marker;

function mkron(x) {
   // some code to get lat lon 
   marker = L.marker([lat, lon]).addTo(map);
}

function mkroff() {
  if(marker){
    map.removeLayer(marker)
    marker = null;
  }
}
```

Comment: Tried the very first suggestion and it worked great! Thanks.